# if else statement not returning anything

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a dashboard for a project that I am working on. I'm using nodejs in my backend with mongodb as my database. I'm trying to calculate total sales tax owed, which in this project's case would be the sales tax of all orders minus the amount of sales tax that is reimbursed to a customer upon a return. For this, I have:

```
const salesTaxOrders = await Order.aggregate([
            {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        taxPrice: { $sum:'$taxPrice'},
                    },
            }
        ]);

        const salesTaxReturns = await Return.aggregate([
            {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        taxPrice: { $sum:'$taxPrice'},
                    },
            }
        ]);
```

Where `salesTaxOrders` is the total amount of sales tax from all orders and `salesTaxReturns` is the total amount of reimbursed sales tax. Currently, there are no returns.

`console.log(salesTaxReturns.length);` gives me 0;

For my calculation, I have:

```
if (salesTaxReturns.length > 0) {
    const salesTax =  salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice - salesTaxReturns[0].taxPrice;
}
else {
    const salesTax =  salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice;
}
```

however `console.log(salesTax)` is not giving/returning anything.

I've also, tried a number of variation of this such as:

```
if (salesTaxReturns[0].taxPrice) {
        const salesTax = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice - salesTaxReturns[0].taxPrice;
}
else {
    const salesTax = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice
}
```

and

```
if (salesTaxReturns.length > 0) {
        const salesTax = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice - salesTaxReturns[0].taxPrice;
}
else if (salesTaxReturns.length === 0) {
    const salesTax = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice
}
```

None of which are giving me a result for console.log(salesTax). Even

```
if (salesTaxReturns.length === 0) {
        const sales = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice - salesTaxReturns[0].taxPrice;
}
else {
    const sales = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice
}
        const salesTax = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice
      console.log(salesTax)
```

is not giving me a result, even though if

```
 const salesTax = salesTaxOrders[0].taxPrice
      console.log(salesTax)
```

was before the if/else statement I would get the number for `console.log(salesTax)`. Does anyone know why this is happening? I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you upload the full code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking for general debug help. If your log statement is not emitting anything, then it's likely not being reached. That could mean something is causing an error earlier in the lifecycle. And since you didn't mention any errors, I'd assume something is catching that error and ignoring it.

What I would do is [enable node debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) and use something like Chrome Dev Tools to inspect